# Linux Shell "Variable" to use for File Input "<"

Tags: linux, shell, variables, redirect, input

I'm trying to make mysql database input from a file. But the `db filename` will be coming from the variable `filename= /file/path/name.sql`. But when input using `<` it is showing `ambiguous redirect` error.

My full script is:

```
filename= /var/backup/mydatabase.sql
echo $filename
mysql -uxxxx -pxxxx -hxxxx databasename < $filename
```

And the output is:

```
/var/backup/mydatabase.sql

./myscript.sh: line 3: $filename: ambiguous redirect
```

Please note followings:

- Please assume the `filename` variable is needed for some reason
- I'm a root user

So my question here is:

- How to use `shell variables` for file input purpose?

Comment: There's really no reason to be running the `mysql` client as root...

Comment: Oh really! Don't do anything as root that is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Also, please do not edit the question so as to destroy the meaningfulness of the answer.  Accept the answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
filename= /var/backup/mydatabase.sql
         ^
```

Spaces around `=` are not allowed when you define a variable.
Please remove the space after `=`.

---

```
./myscript.sh: line 3: $filename: ambiguous redirect
```

This error message tells your that `$filename` may expand to multi-words.
Please double-quote `"$filename"`.

---

Make sure that script file doesn't contain any invisible ctrl-chars at end of line.
Use command `xxd myscript.sh` to check.

Comment: Yes.  You are setting `filename` to nothing and then attempting to run `/var/backup/mydatabase.sql` as a command, which should produce an error message before the ambiguous redirect thing.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right.  The assignment should be `filename=/var/backup/mydatabase.sql`.  No spaces anywhere.  If you do that and still get an error, then you have either typoed the variable name in one of the two lines, or your simplified version of the problem is too simplified.

Comment: NO. Please see my output (i edited). The `$filename` is coming. Problem is not that.

Comment: Is the filename really `/var/backup/mydatabase.sql`, or does it maybe have a space in it?

Comment: NO SPACE between :/ .. and not working also with this `filename=/var/backup/mydatabase.sql` :/